# get selected value in react js autcomplete on key press enter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete

i want to set value to input box when user press "ENTER" key, in my react autocomplete component

for options i have useRef , trying to get hold of option elements.

```
  const optionsRef = useRef([]);
```

and below is Autocomplete render

```
 return (
        <div ref={wrapperRef} style={{ width: '100%' }} className="flex-container flex-column pos-rel">
            <input autoComplete='off'
                id="auto"
                onClick={(e) => onClickInput(e)}
                placeholder="Type to search"
                value={search} onKeyDown={(e) => handleKeyDown(e)}
                onChange={event => onClickAuto(event)}
            /><Button onClick={(e) => clear(e, '')}>X</Button>
            {display && (
                <div className="autoContainer">
                    {options.length > 0 && options
                        .filter((item, ind) => item.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) > -1)
                        .map((item, i) => {
                            return (
                                <div id='option' ref={ref =>optionsRef[i] = ref }
                                    onClick={(e) => updateValue(e.target.value, item)}
                                    className={cursor === i ? 'active' : 'option'}
                                    key={i}
                                    tabIndex="0"
                                >
                                    <span >{item}</span>
                                </div>
                            );
                        })}
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};
```

and onclick of input box i am trying to get key press enter, and set the value which is currently active on dropdown menu  based on className

> className={cursor === i ? 'active' : 'option'}

and my handler for keypress event.

```
 const handleKeyDown = (e) => {

// arrow up/down button should select next/previous list element
if(e.keyCode === 13){
  // need to set value which is current active on the options menu
}
if (e.keyCode === 38 && cursor > 0) {
    let count = cursor - 1;
    setCursor(count)
} else if (e.keyCode === 40 && cursor < options.length - 1) {
    let count = cursor + 1;
    setCursor(count)
}
```

}

in below image, option value 'pump boys' is active, and on press 'ENTER' it has to set value to the input box.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Added the below *onKeyDown* in a simple example code from [MUI Components Docs - Autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/) and it works. When a choice is active, on press Enter it is set as a value.

```js
<Autocomplete
  disablePortal
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={top100Films}
  sx={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
  // If enter is pressed on this input do not submit the form but set the selected value
  onKeyDown={e => {
    e.key === 'Enter' && e.preventDefault()
  }}
/>
```